# Tier 1 support for Ubuntu 20.04 & any support for Raspberry Pi 'Buster'

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Just wondered if we had a date for tier 1 support on Ubuntu 20.04?
Also - any word on any support for Raspberry Pi 'Buster' OS version.

Comment: Raspbian Buster was renamed Raspberry Pi OS, it has tier 1 support. It was recently changed in the [docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/66577)

Comment: We've renamed Raspbian to Raspberry Pi OS in the docs, but Stretch is still Tier 1 and Buster is still Tier 2. Ubuntu 20.04 and Raspberry Pi Buster will be the next updates, but there isn't a date just yet.